# Make elements fill given space equally

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I would like to have layout of div elements that looks like below:

If screen is large enough then there is many blocks in the single row.

For example, I would like to have minimum width of each block set to 250px.

So on large screens I can have the following for such elements. On the right is the map (closable), if user hide it then there will be 6 blocks in the row.

[image: large screen]

Next when I shrink the browser window horizontally this all block doesn't fit in the row so they move to the next row. Ok this works now in that way that they go do second row, but they leave space between div blocks and the map. Like on the below image.

[image: ramaining space between divs and map sidebar]

I would like to have such layout where if 4 blocks doesn't fit the space then ok there is 3 blocks but they equally fill the remaining space (without this remaining yellow space). See pictures below.

[image: 3 blocks of divs per row]

Then when browser windows shrinks more it should look like below

[image: 2 blocks of divs per row]

And on mobile devices and very narrow browser windows:

[image: 1 block of div per row]

Ok I could achieve something like this using such CSS style:

```
#parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
    width: calc(33% - 15px);
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;  
    min-width: 250px;
}
```

then I should manually change this using media queries:

```
calc(25% - 15px) //lg
calc(33% - 15px) //md
calc(50% - 15px) //sm
calc(100% - 15px) //xs
```

maybe even this when map disappears

```
calc(16.667% - 15px) //lg+no map
```

Ok FLEX isn't so backward-compatible so I could play even more and do something like this:

```
#parent {

}

.child {
    width: calc(33% - 15px);
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;  
    min-width: 250px;
    float: left; 
}
```

then also change this width depending on screen size manually 
and add **clear: left** after last element using

```
.block-offer:nth-last-child(1):after { 
    clear: left; 
}
```

or before other elements make some other clearfix

or even (**is it necessery?**)  add clear: left after each row using:

```
.block-offer:nth-child(4n+1) { 
   clear:left; 
}
.block-offer:nth-child(3n+1) { 
   clear:left; 
}
.block-offer:nth-child(2n+1) { 
   clear:left; 
}
.block-offer:nth-child(1n+1) { 
   clear:left; 
}
```

like with this width: calc() depending on screen size and divs witdh

But then I need to use many media queries and I would like to wrap this CSS in some angular 2+ component and have there only such things like:

```
<blocks-container max-cols="6"> 
    <block min-width="250px"></block> 
    <block min-width="250px"></block>
     ...
</blocks-container>
```

I think that using @media queries will improve a little this behaviour but my components will tightly coupled with screen size and I think there wasn't as generic as I would like them to be to flexibly specify max-cols and min-widths.

Comment: Hey there. If you're still around, can you vote for the answers and maybe accept one, or possibly comment why it's not applicable to your situation? @Michael's answer looks like it does what you need in the most css-grid-ish way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution, which combines CSS flexbox and grid:

```css
body {
  display: flex;                 /* 1 */
}
article {                        /* 2 */
  flex: 1;                       /* 2 */                   
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: grid;                 /* 3 */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));  /* 4 */
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;         /* 5 */
  grid-gap: 10px;                /* 6 */
}
map {
  min-height: 200px;            /* 7 */
  width: 250px;
  background-color: orangered;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {     /* 8 */
  map { display: none; }
}
section {                       
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</article>
<map></map>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gazhzh0z/1/)

Notes:

1. Create a flex container with two flex items.
2. The first item (`article`) holds the wrapping blocks (`section`). It's set to `flex: 1` to consume all available width.
3. The first item is made into a grid container, so grid properties can be 
   applied to the blocks.
4. See below.
5. The [**`grid-auto-rows`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks) property sets the height of automatically generated rows.
6. The [**`grid-gap`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#gutters) property is a shorthand for `grid-column-gap` and `grid-row-gap`. This rule set a 10px gap between grid items.
7. The second flex item is the map (`map`), which is aligned right due to `flex: 1` on its sibling.
8. The media query removes the map, to simulate user behavior.

The [**`auto-fill`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-repeat) function allows the grid to line up as many grid tracks (columns or rows) as possible without overflowing the container. This can create similar behavior to flex layout's `flex-wrap: wrap`.

The [**`minmax()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#valdef-grid-template-columns-minmax) function sets a minimum and maximum size range for a grid track. In the code above, the width of column tracks will be a minimum of 250px and maximum of whatever free space is available (`1fr`). This prevents the display of empty space.

The [**`fr`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit) unit represents a fraction of the available space. It is similar to `flex-grow` in flex layout.

**Browser Support for CSS Grid**

- Chrome - full support as of March 8, 2017 (version 57)
- Firefox - full support as of March 6, 2017 (version 52)
- Safari - full support as of March 26, 2017 (version 10.1)
- Edge - full support as of October 16, 2017 (version 16)
- IE11 - no support for current spec; supports obsolete version

Here's the complete picture: http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the float method, you should do sth like :

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sntvaoer/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="col">
   <div class="content">
       <p>Content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* complete with your style */
.col { display:block; width:25%; border-sizing:border:box; float:left; padding:10px; }

@media (max-width: 1280px) { 

.col { width:33%; }

}

@media (max-width: 1024px) { 

.col { width:50%; }

}

@media (max-width: 768px) { 

.col { width:100%; }

}
```

If you want to use the flex method, order your html by row, then use `flex-wrap:wrap;` and `width:250px` or `min-width:250px: width:25%`, and play with the media queries as above

Answer (score 0):

You could refer this as an example, you could do that using `flex` or using `media query` to change `style` for elements at different `break points` as below, this gives more understanding of what changes are made.

Check this jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sjf5ms08/

```css
#box{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
#box > .b1, .b2, .b3, .b4, .b5, .b6{
  width:33%;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px){
#box > .b1, .b2, .b3, .b4, .b5, .b6{
  width:250px;
  height:150px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background:blue;
  }  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px){
#box > .b1, .b2, .b3, .b4, .b5, .b6{
  width:33%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background:yellow;
  }  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px){
#box > .b1, .b2, .b3, .b4, .b5, .b6{
  width:49%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background:green;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="b1">1</div>
  <div class="b2">2</div>
  <div class="b3">3</div>
  <div class="b4">4</div>
  <div class="b5">5</div>
  <div class="b6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pirs that's for aligning 2 div at small screen resolution. That could work even if I change display to block and style with margin using %, but as it's display:inline-block so by default there is spacing between div. Op need one parent div and inside that there are 6 different div with different conditions so media query surely will be needed different break-points.

Comment: At least, you could put font-size:0; to the parent and font-size:inherit; to the child, put 1% less to make this possible its just the worst idea you could find.... god

Comment: @Pirs it's for understanding for purpose, so in this condition not needed, if needed could add and replace that by margin to add spacing between divs.

Comment: I know this approach is fine but fixed to screen division into blocks 4,3,2,1 and screen sizes where the change should happen. So I think there is simple solution in CSS of autofilling remaining space if min-width blocks doesn't fit and also doesn't fill entirely the row. 
When developing angular component I would like to have possibility to specify any number of max columns and min-width of blocks like max 15 columns and min-width: 100px, but it seems to have many code logic in javascript to achive generic solution?

Comment: the best approach is flex, then float ... but inline-block will be with white-space that only custom css could avoid...

Comment: float is more backward compatible i think? 
What about media queries this max-width it relates to screen width? Isn't there possibility to us media max-width of parent component? (then if map will disappear other media selector will be chosen?

Comment: float is fully compatible yes... Even if its a hack, its the most stable for now, look at my fiddle above

Comment: @MichałZiobro that's true this works as a fixed division and in your case what you could do is use media-query at different break-points or you could use jQuery resize to change the width of div at certain screen resolution. min-width and max-width works as conditions that at-least width of element should be any length.

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying `flex` on the cards (flex-grow/ flex-shrink/ flex-basis)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.child:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.child:nth-child(2n+3) {
  background: rgb(244, 241, 194);
}

.child {
  margin: 10px 10px 20px 0;
  min-width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 1 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0jc93hqn/